# Set sort column using data attribute from table head

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery dataTable, and I want to define which columns to be sorted in the html, like this:

```
<table id="report">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-order="false">Code</th>
      <th data-order="true">Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

In javascript initialization it iterate through the columns and set order parameter only ones with `"data-order=true"`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work:

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/12736/setting-sortable-with-aocolumndefs-glitched

in javascript:

```
var oOptions = {
  aoColumnDefs: [
    {aTargets: ['searchable'], bSearchable: true},
    {aTargets: ['sortable'], bSortable: true},
    {aTargets: ['_all'], bSortable: false, bSearchable: true}
  ]
};

$('#table_report').dataTable(oOptions);
```

in html use the class "sortable" in the column:

```
<th class="sortable">Header X</th>
```